# Error on running YouTube Activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-youtube-api

Working on a Youtube App in Android Studio. I keep on getting the error:

> The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

I have read documents and looked online but I can't seem to find a solution to this. What can I do about this? I will paste my `main-activity` code below.

**YoutubeActivity.java**

```
package com.code.mohamedali.hackathon2018;

import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class YoutubeActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity
      implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener  {

    private static final String TAG = "YoutubeActivity";
    static final String  GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyDMS4J2hlSJqCZsNL1Owqcups91vGQiF3I";
    static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEO = "d-diB65scQU";
    static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST = "RDQMhH0aPyrY-R0";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

    ConstraintLayout mylayout = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_youtube,null);
    setContentView(mylayout);

    YouTubePlayerView playerView = new YouTubePlayerView(this);
    playerView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mylayout.addView(playerView);
    playerView.initialize(GOOGLE_API_KEY,this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onInitializationSuccess: provider is " + provider.getClass().toString() );
    Toast.makeText(this,"Initliazed youtube player succesfully" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    // Now we are using the Event Listener and the StateChange Listener
    youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);



    if(!wasRestored){
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(YOUTUBE_VIDEO);
    }


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    if(youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()){
        youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this,REQUEST_CODE).show();
    }else{
        String errorMessage = String.format("There was an error initialiazing youtube player (%1$s)", youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this,errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}


private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
        Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this, "Good, video is playing ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
        Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this, "Good, video is paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this,"Video has been stopped" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int i) {

    }
};

private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoading() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
        Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this,"Click Ad now, make me rich" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
        Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this,"Video has started" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this,"You have reached the end of the 
video" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

    }
};

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.code.mohamedali.hackathon2018">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".YoutubeActivity"
    android:label="Youtube Player">
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @ArunJ: errors are best shown in a quote block (or sometimes a code block if the contain angle brackets). Bold or inline code is not ideal, in my view, since it is not sufficiently draw attention to the most important feature of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `android:exported="true"` to `Activity`.

```
<activity android:name=".YoutubeActivity"
 android:exported="true"
android:label="Youtube Player">
</activity>
```

Make sure the Run configuration for app contain `MainActivity` as launcher .